# React scafolds function instead of class declaration by default

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am completely a newbie in react coming from Angular Typescript background. I chose to learn React with Typescript to make my transition easier compared to learning react with javascript. Could somebody let me know nice fundamental videos on React with Typescript. There is fundamental video on Plural sight but can its demonstrated using javascript.

I have created an app using the create-react-app command which has scaffold of react project.

I have noticed that file has following declaration of const while the examples that i see on the videos shows a class declaration with a render method. Could somebody explain ?

Scafolded output

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The example is not in typescript

Comment: There are 2 ways to define a component with React: with a function or with a class: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: Hi Mukesh, If it isnt in typescript then could you show me an example

Answer (score 0):

In React there are 2 ways to define a component: with a function (Functional Component) or with a class (Class Component), you could check the exact differences [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). This post from [Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) attack that topic also (And give and inside on good practices).

But basically, both definitions are ok, but you have to be sure how you would want to use a component for, in order to decide between Funcional or Class components. Another good resource [here](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108).

Also for react training courses, you could check these resources:

- [React External Resources](https://reactjs.org/community/external-resources.html)
- [React with Typescript](https://alligator.io/react/typescript-with-react/)
- [How to Use Typescript with React and Redux](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/how-to-use-typescript-with-react-and-redux-a118b1e02b76)
- [Official Typescript with React tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html)
- [Also some Youtube options](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=react%20%2B%20typescript%20)
- [Good Pluralsight tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/typescript-react-getting-started)

Comment: Is there good training view on react with typescript fundamentals

Comment: I've updated my response and put some good resources to start.

Comment: i can see good examples of video tutorials explaining React with Javascript but not with typescript. The two links above just show the basic setup with typescript.